# Открытие H.265 для работы с NAL-unit'ами

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, видео, кодек

Есть видео mkv с кодеком h.265. Как его открыть, чтобы провести его синтаксический анализ на уровне «NAL-unit»-ов.  При обнаружении очередного «NAL-unit»-а анализировать его заголовок и определить тип «NAL-unit»-а.
Есть опыт открытия лишь txt файлов, для чего не требовалось ничего, кроме `<fstream>`.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно тут подразумевается под "начать работать", но если уж есть опыт открытия только txt файлов, то лучше сначала прокачать навыки С++.

Comment: Переформулировал.

Comment: Ну видимо вам надо будет взять какой-нибудь демуксер mkv, например из libav, достать с его помощью видео поток и распарсить его в соответствии со спецификацией itu. Под идее nal юниты должны лежать наверху, а необходимые структуры и код можно подсмотреть в той же libav.